# Good partition size for insertion sort in mixed quicksort

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort

I wrote a quicksort algorithm that has an insertion sort stub inside, which is called if the partition to sort is N elements or shorter.

I tested on an old Core 2 machine and the result was that sorting one million ints took 140 milliseconds with pure quicksort and less time for mixed quicksort + insertion sort.

What surprised me was that the partition size on which I called insertion sort needed to be quite large to obtain the best result (best was 114 milliseconds) – about 70, though there wasn’t a very big difference from 60 to 100. For shorter partition sizes, like 10, it was slower.

Why is that so? Is this a typical, correct result?

Is there something that will work yet faster? (Note `std::sort` from the C++ standard library takes 111 ms in my tests, only a tiny bit better than 114 ms.)

Comment: What kind of input were you testing on?

Comment: int tab[1000*1000] assigned to random ints up to 2^24  (only positive)

Comment: I remember doing this in Java, switching from merge sort to insertion sort for small arrays, and finding ~80 as the optimal threshold. In Python I think the threshold is usually lower, possibly because Python doesn't get much benefit from working "in-place". I would say your result is not unusual.

Comment: The performance of insertion sort ranges from O(n) to O(n^2) depending on the data. What I would do is add some debugging code that keeps track of how much work (on average) the insertion sorts are doing. The other characteristic of insertion sort is that it has a comparatively low constant factor. So if quicksort is using a high-constant-factor pivot selection method (e.g. median of medians), that will tend to favor larger sizes for insertion sort.

Comment: What was the time when the partition size for insertion sort was 10?

Comment: i dont know i thought it was generally expected to be less..if its square then the n^2 explosion appears, but maybe thiose partitions are sorta sorted by quicksort (?) so it is noy square

Comment: Depending on cache size, the range is usually 32 to 96, Around 128, it's break even.